# Bootstrap Inline Block is not working properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Check out this website: http://pazomall.storehippo.com/

You can see the top menu where there are 3 options (My Account, Need Help & Cart)! As you can see the Cart doesn't go inline with other options.

I tried `display: inline-block;` but it doesn't work at all. Please help me to make those menus inline (use chrome developer tools).

Comment: use `col-md-4` grid instead of 4,5,3 grid

Comment: _“Check out this website”_ - and you please check out [ask] and [mcve]. All code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question.

Comment: Sorry for the question structure @CBroe ! Will keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using col-md-3, that 3 menus will not fit in 25% width of col-md-3

option 1. You can change the col-md-5 to col-md-4 of search bar and make col-md-3 of menu section to col-md-4

option 2. you can change col-md-4 of logo to col-md-3 then change col-md-3 of menu section to col-md-4 - use this, incase if you dont want to reduce the search bar length

Comment: Thanks a lot @charan ! I guess I have to mark yours the answer.

Answer (score 1):

3 options need more space. So please updates update your column structure. Then it will be working well.

Please check the screenshot http://prntscr.com/jshz54

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to align the 'cart' with 'My Account' and 'Need Help' because the div containing these lists has class 'col-md-3' and the first two list items have taken its whole width thats why it is wrapping below. SO you need to give the class col-md-4 or above if you want them to align horizontally.